# Error when simulating xcode project on a computer running an older version

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new to programming and I was working on xcode when I got this error. I think the reason behind this is that I working on xcode 6.1 but the computer I'm trying to simulate the project on runs 5.0  What can I do to fix this issue? Thanks!

The Error is:

```
[BEROR]No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=armv6 armv7). [BEROR]Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain
```

Comment: Working on XCode 6.1 is almost definitely problematic.  That's got to be early, early alpha stage, right?  But either way, it's not related.  Please, read the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Xcode 6.1 doesn't exist yet, so that's a problem. You're most likely working on Xcode 4 or 5. I believe you mean iOS 6.1.

Anyway, the issue is that you are trying to build for an architecture (x86_64) that isn't one of the valid architectures for iOS (armv6 or armv7). You'll need to change your build configuration to build for armv6 or armv7. Your best bet is to go to your Build Settings and just change it to whatever the standard architectures are for your version of Xcode.

The second error is related to your provisioning profiles, certificates, etc. They aren't configured correctly. Those are difficult to work with, so see if Xcode can do it for you through Preferences->Accounts.